# using kohana url rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, frameworks, kohana

I know that kohana inteprets the url like

```
/controller/method/variable/etc..
```

is there a way to make it intepret it as

```
/variable/controller/method/etc..
```

Comment: Which Kohana version are you using?

Comment: using the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the default route to this in your `bootstrap.php`:

```
Route::set('default', '(<variable>/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'main',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```